# Power Automate - Lookup column B, if equals specific text add date into column Z

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm completely new to this type of posting but this is a huge cry for help after what feels like hitting my head against a wall all day trying to learn.

What I'm wanting to do is have a Excel document in SharePoint which if Column B (drop-down) is changed to the option "SLR Review", then in the corresponding row in Column Z to put today's date as a datestamp. I need this to run in real-time or I could possible learn to setup a automation at a set frequency.

**Key points: **

- The document is located: /Shared Documents/1. EV/Group questionnaire
- The title of the spreadsheet is: Full questionnaire.xlsx
- The spreadsheet is in a Table (Table1)
- The Column name for B is "Status"
- The Column name for Z is "Status to SLR Review" (where the datestamp needs to go)

I have setout the following:

**"When a file is created or modified (properties only)**
Site addres: Site link from dropdown
Library name: Documents
Folder: /Shared Documents/1. EV/Group questionnaire

**Condition**
I am so lost with this?! Help!

**If yes**
**Update a row**
Location: Drop-down site
Document library: Documents
File: /Shared Documents/1. EV/Group questionnaire/Full questionnaire.xlsx
Table: Table1
Key Column: Status
Key Value: SLR Review

(further down)
Status to SLR Review: The expression: `formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

I really hope someone can help out step-by-step with this one as I'm a complete novice trying to learn from others who've done similar things, but I just cannot get it.

Thank you!
FC

Comment: You have a couple of issues, firstly,  PowerAutomate can’t trigger an event for a specific cell/row change, so anything you do needs to be done in bulk. Secondly, it can’t be in real time because there is no direct event process in Excel online. You would need to open the document in Excel desktop and use old style macros. So basically, the approach you’re taking is really the only way. Regarding your condition, you first need to get the rows from the table and loop over each one of them. Your condition will be in the loop.